# Strange MS Word malware?

Tags: ms-word

I'm running the Word 2016 on Windows 10.  Every time I run it I get this strange string added to my registry.

Key:
%af%0f%c6%cb%b5%f6%36%4b%00%ac%5b%65%0b%15%f8%42%05%c6%87%d9%da%9a%2b%b3%0c%ba%77%df%55%1f%f0%08

Value:
441FE2AA79C27FEE3559FE71CAF8E2BE6155FD5F4EA33CCBEB37A6C37DDD8A19

Under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

I think its malware but can't figure out how it gets there.  Anyone have any idea what I can do or what it means?

Comment: Is this the only indication you have of "malware"? What made you go looking there?

Comment: the regkey kept coming back shortly before I would be reinfected.  then I noticed it only ever got there after I ran word.  very strange.

Comment: Try starting Word in safemode (by pressing the Ctrl key while starting Word). If the key does not come back then, you have an add-in that is responsible for that entry. Check *File* -> *Options* -> *Add-ins* to see what gets loaded.